# Mysql select only numbers from substring result

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I've this query

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(post_content,INSTR(post_content, '[table'),16) as substring,
ID FROM `wp276_posts`
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%[table%' 
AND `post_status` = 'publish' 
ORDER BY `ID` ASC
```

that returns this results:

[image]

How can I select only the the number part of the substring?

e.g. of the needed result:

```
+-----------+------+
| substring | ID   |
+-----------+------+
| 22        | 5072 |
+-----------+------+
| 67        | 5757 |
+-----------+------+
| 54        | 8550 |
+-----------+------+
```

Comment: Please show examples of post_content

Comment: The fact that you are not using substring_index suggest your current query may be sub optimal..

Comment: post_content is a WordPress post and could be everything.

If a string that begin with [table is found, I need to take the number after id=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUBSTRING_INDEX` might work here:

```
SELECT
    post_content,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, '[table id=', -1), ' ', 1) AS id
FROM wp276_posts
WHERE
    post_content LIKE '%[table%' AND
    post_status = 'publish'   -- you seem to want equivalence here
ORDER BY
    ID;
```

The inner call to `SUBSTRING_INDEX` above returns everything to the *right* of `[table id=`.  The outer call then takes what is to the *left* of the space which is presumed to follow the `id` number.

Comment: a little edit of your answer seems to work:


SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, '[table id=', -1), ' ', 1) AS substring, 
ID FROM `wp276_posts` 
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%[table%' 
AND `post_status` = 'publish' 
ORDER BY `ID` ASC

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `SUBSTRING()` and `INSTR()` functions combination :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(post_content,INSTR(post_content, 'id=')+3,
                 INSTR(post_content, ' /') - INSTR(post_content, 'id=') - 3
                 ) as substring, ID
  FROM t
 WHERE .....
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7b82a177d27894411dfeee7a05ff577)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

With ficc´xed text you can use REPLACE

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(post_content," /]",""),"[tabelid= ","") as substring
    , ID 
FROM 
    `wp276_posts` 
WHERE 
    `post_content` LIKE '%[table%' 
    AND `post_status` LIKE 'publish' 
ORDER BY `ID` ASC
```